# Get AD Groups from Azure AD in MVC application

Tags: azure

We have used the below code to get Azure AD groups in our MVC web application. But after publishing the application if we run the page, the below code will get only 100 AD groups (Current page) and not getting all the AD groups. How to get all the Azure AD groups instead of current page groups?

```
public async Task<List<Group>> Index(string KYCUserStartsWith)
{
    CreateErrorLog("ADGroups:Start", "log");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("GetADGroups");
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    List<Group> groupList = new List<Group>();
    string searchString = KYCUserStartsWith;
    try
    {
        ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient();
        IPagedCollection<IGroup> pagedCollection = client.Groups.Where(group => group.DisplayName.StartsWith(searchString)).ExecuteAsync().Result;
        do
        {                   
            List<IGroup> directoryGroups = pagedCollection.CurrentPage.ToList();
            foreach (IGroup directoryGroup in directoryGroups)
            {
                groupList.Add((Group)directoryGroup);
            }
            pagedCollection = pagedCollection.GetNextPageAsync().Result;
        } while (pagedCollection != null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return groupList;
}
```